# Do until missing

Tags: sas

My goal is to loop through an array, say `VAR_` of some length which I am not given. However, I do know that if `VAR_n` is missing, then so is `VAR_n+1` and so on. My attempt is to use a `%DO %UNTIL` loop of the following variety:

```
DATA dsn;
    SET my_dataset;
    %LET hold = 0;
    %LET i = 1;

    %DO %UNTIL (&hold);
        IF NOT MISSING(VAR_&i) THEN DO;
            *** Do stuff ;
            CALL SYMPUT('hold', 1);
        END;
        ELSE DO;
            %LET i = %EVAL(&i+1);
        END;
    %END;
RUN;
```

I have tried using `%LET` instead of `CALL SYMPUT`, however it seems that `%LET` is executed without regard for conditional statements.

I have tried using `ARRAY MYVAR VAR_:;` and `i > DIM(MYVAR)` in my `%DO %UNTIL`, which didn't work. I received the following error:
    Required operator not found in expression: &i > dim(myarr)
    The condition in the %DO %UNTIL loop, &i > dim(myarr), yielded an
    invalid or missing value, .

Comment: "It didn't work" is not a problem statement.  Please specify the behavior that you expect and the behavior that you are actually getting.  I'm not that familiar with SAS, but it seems like you closed your first IF with an END prematurely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing up macro and data step code here in a way you can't.  You likely can do this:

```
DATA dsn;
    SET my_dataset;
    array vars var_:;
    do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
       if missing(vars[_i]) then leave; *leaves the loop;
       *_do stuff_;
    end;
RUN;
```

If you can't for some reason, this is probably possible:

```
DATA dsn;
    SET my_dataset;
    array vars var_:;
    do _i = 1 to dim(vars);
        if input(scan(vname(vars[_i]),-1,'_'),??best12.) > 0 then do;
          *_do stuff_;
        end;
    end;
RUN;
```

That checks to see if it has a numeric suffix; then it's probably in your list of variables.  That's the major reason why it might not be possible.

If not, then you should find out what the correct variable end point for the array is externally, and then do the coding that way (ie, something like take a proc contents, find the highest var_####, and store that #### in a macro variable, then `array vars var_1-var_&highestnum.;` or something like that.)

You also might want to explain what else you're doing; this might not be the best general approach to your problem.

Comment: This works perfectly. I was indeed using macro and data step code in a way I couldn't. Thank you for teaching me something!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a misunderstanding as to how SAS macro code works.

Generally speaking, especially within a data step, macro code is resolved (executed and/or turned into SAS code) prior to SAS code execution. So when you say something like "%let is executed without regard for conditional statements," what's actually happening is that the %let is resolved prior to a non-macro conditional.

So, for example, if you have the following:

```
if (false) then do;
%let macrovar = 1;
end;
```

&macrovar. will equal 1. If you wanted to put the macrovar in a conditional, you could instead do:

```
%if 0 %then %do;
%let macrovar = 1;
%end;
```

Which would not execute that %let statement. Because macro code is resolved before SAS code is executed, that means you cannot reference a macro variable you conditionally create within the same data step. For a better, non-macro, way to handle what you're trying to accomplish, look at what Joe's written while I typed this out.